# nested objects in thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm trying to build a form using thymeleaf, my entity includes Collection (List) of objects. I'm struggling to build a proper form for this case.

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
public class Owner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Phone> phones;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<Pet> pets;

//getterss and setters
```

this is the Pet.class

```
@Entity
public class Pet {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "pet_name")
    private String petName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_Id")
    private Owner owner; 

//getters and setters
```

and this is my html file for building the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http:/www.thymealeaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"></meta>
<title>Add new owner to database</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="form">
        <form th:action="@{/addOwner.do}" th:object="${Owner}" method="post">

            <label for="firstName">First Name: </label> 
            <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" /> 

            <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" /> 

            <!-- Here is the core problem -->
            <label for="pets">Pet Name: </label>
            <input type="text" th:each="pet : *{pets}"/> 

            <input type="submit" value="add" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

so I'm struggling with this:

```
 <!-- Here is the core problem -->
                <label for="pets">Pet Name: </label>
                <input type="text" th:each="pet : *{pets}"/>
```

my problem is, I dont know how to access Pet object in List collection inside of the form so that i could make an input of petName property.

//edit or maybe there is a different way to do this? the obvious way is getting a string from form and then in controller building the string to pet name before adding the object to database?

Answer (score 2):

can you try this and let me know if this worked for you

```
<div th:each="pet, stat : *{pets}"> 
   <input type="text" th:field="*{pet[__${stat.index}__].petName}" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: it does not work, there is no 'input field' for this solution, I've solved this with 

<label for="pets[0].petName">Pet Name: </label>
<input type="text" th:field="*{pets[0].petName}"/> 

this allows only to insert one Pet, which makes the relaation OneToMany useless, nevertheless the best solution here would be dynamic generated form with usage of java script, so that we could click e.g "add next Pet" on the same page - I guess, so I'll leave it as it is, for now.

Comment: Don't you want to show the generated pets in the list?

Comment: nope, it's input form to database, i dont intend to view the entity's properties, just create one and save it to database